# ArchLinux, PostgreSQL and pgAdmin4

Tags: backend, psql, pgadmin, archlinux

I'm trying to make pgAdmin4 work with PostgreSQL on Arch Linux, but when  I open pgAdmin, I get the following error:

```
QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
Semaphore name: "pgadmin4-vino-a59283b86ae8ae85d20fdf770d799dd7-sema"
Shared memory segment name: "pgadmin4-vino-a59283b86ae8ae85d20fdf770d799dd7-shmem"
QIODevice::read (QFile, "/home/vino/.local/share/pgadmin4.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.addr"): device not open
Already running. Opening browser tab to:  "" and exiting.
```

Before that, I used to get a Connection refused error, but now I'm getting the one above.

PostgreSQL is running fine on my system, on localhost port 5432 as default.

Is there a way for me to specify which browser pgadmin4 is supposed to use? I've been searching on google, but every result shows me a dialog box inside the pgadmin4 application, but the problem is that it won't even open on my machine to begin with.

Should I edit a config file somewhere in my system?

Comment: Are you using latest pgAdmin ? Latest pgAdmin does not use Qt.

Comment: Yes. Just so we're clear, all I did was install it through pacman, I did not mess with any config files at all. My system is up to date.

Comment: pgadmin is not available on pacman. Please check www.pgadmin.org/downloads

Comment: Yes, it is
https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=pgadmin4
But I haven't tried to install it through the pgadmin.org source code yet. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The link says pgAdmin v4.30. The latest version of pgAdmin is v6.3. I'm from pgAdmin developer team. pgAdmin is not officially published on pacman. And https://www.pgadmin.org/downloads is not source code. It has the official installers build by pgAdmin team.

Answer (score 4):

First remove any existing pgadmin installed and then try this:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/pgadmin
$ sudo mkdir /var/log/pgadmin
$ sudo chown $USER /var/lib/pgadmin
$ sudo chown $USER /var/log/pgadmin
$ python3 -m venv pgadmin4
$ source pgadmin4/bin/activate
(pgadmin4) $ pip install pgadmin4
...
(pgadmin4) $ pgadmin4
NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.

Enter the email address and password to use for the initial pgAdmin user account:

Email address: user@domain.com
Password: 
Retype password:
Starting pgAdmin 4. Please navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5050 in your browser.
 * Serving Flask app "pgadmin" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

[Official Documentation Link](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/)
[Answer Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/nf9i0y/comment/hidkmco/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)