# How to open pgadmin4 on Manjaro

Tags: linux, pgadmin, manjaro

I was tried to open pgadmin4 on linux Manjaro but i have an error. I don't know how to fix it. Please help me [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSOBi.png)

Comment: The same issue. I was told in Manjaro forums to use dbeaver instead because pgadmin hasn't been working in Manjaro for years; you have to consider that pgadmin now it's just a webapp and as such, it needs a proper environment (python, pip, etc)if it's not packaged properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed the https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/pgadmin4/ app. This is a community edition and is not supported by the official Pgadmin4 maintainers (by this comment: [ArchLinux, PostgreSQL and pgAdmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483178/archlinux-postgresql-and-pgadmin4#comment124739684_70483178)). I wasn't able to get it up and running too.

The solution is to follow the official installation, which uses `pip`. You can find it here: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/. Note that this only runs in a python venv.

You could also run a docker container, which might be even simpler: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-container/